# Mishna Megila 4:4 - how many pesukim can you read to a meturgeman?

Tags: mishna, tractate-megillah

The Mishna in Megila 4:4 say you can only read one Torah verse at a time to the translator, so he doesn't get confused.

> לֹא יִקְרָא לַמְּתֻרְגְּמָן יוֹתֵר מִפָּסוּק אֶחָד, וּבַנָּבִיא שְׁלֹשָׁה.

Later the Mishna says:

> מְדַלְּגִין בַּנָּבִיא וְאֵין מְדַלְּגִין בַּתּוֹרָה. וְעַד כַּמָּה הוּא מְדַלֵּג, עַד כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִפְסֹק הַמְּתֻרְגְּמָן:

which the Bartenura explains based on the conclusion of the Gemara:

> **ואין מדלגין בתורה**. בשני ענינים. אבל בענין אחד מדלגין. כמו שהיה כהן גדול קורא ביום הכפורים פרשת אחרי מות, ומדלג וקורא אך בעשור:

Which means you can skip to a different Torah section as long as the topic is the same, and the translator hasn't finished translating yet, per the Mishna in Yoma.

But I thought you can only read one verse at a time to the translator?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly.

You read the last verse of the first section. As the translator is translating that single verse, you skip ahead to the second section.

You have to be able to start reading the first verse of the second section by the time the translator finishes translating the last verse of the first section.

Comment: I guess I assumed that is very little skipping that is possible to be done during the translation of a single verse.